# Setting up a scheduled event in AWS Lambda as alternative to crontab WGET

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cron

So, i have numerous crons that I run every minute for different services such as

- - - - - wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://localhost/close
- - - - - wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://server1/close
- - - - - wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://server2/close
- - - - - wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://server3/close

How do i write a single AWS Lambda (Node) script and set a timer for 1 minute to call the required URLs? I dont need to see the output of these scripts.

Preferably be able to add more URLs that are invoked every minute and remove dependance on crontab fully and use AWS Lambda task to run every minute.

Comment: Minimum interval for lambda scheduling is 5 mins intervals (It relies on Cloudwatch events, wich is 5 min intervals). as per documentation "the minimum precision for schedules is five minutes." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: other limitation you could face: your urls have to be publicly accessible, as lambda can not access your machines through their private address yet. As Lambda IP addresses is volatile and may change over time, this may be a security/architecture concern

Comment: Lambda is not the solution. A t2.micro will do the job much better and cheaper.

Comment: Or a [`t2.nano`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-update-t2-nano-instances-now-available/)!